# How to go end of Page in jquery? using Android 4.04 samsung?

Tags: jquery, cordova

how to using phonegap + cordova 2.7 .I want to go end of the page .I try lot of thing but now work any thing.

```
var $div = $("#realTimeContents");
$div.scrollTop($div[0].scrollHeight);
```

secondly

```
 window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: is this html5 page If yes than check do u add <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: I already added this <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

Comment: do u want to scroll on click or scrollmove

Comment: actually I have one div in which I have some contented Now I want to go at the end of contend .This code work fine in Ipad but problem in samsung tablet

Comment: follow this  http://jsfiddle.net/q6Wsp/6/

Comment: not working in android tablet..:(

Comment: In my experiences, scrolling is not very fun across mobile device.  This is also an issue on iOS.  The most consistent one is find is scrollTop and scroll to a static element: http://jsfiddle.net/YUhgF/

Comment: checking ..? is there any way to scroll the div contend mean add iscroll in the div